# SOLR Pagination

Tags: solr, pagination

I am a newbie to SOLR and I am using SOLRQuery to query a DB and return data that gets downloaded. A number of rows returned is in millions.

The flow is something like
In GUI, click a download button > through REST, java code uses SOLRQuery to fetch the data and the returns it to the GUI, where the data is downloaded as a file.

Since the number of rows is too many, I am little worried about the time it takes to get the data and download the file. So, is it required to have pagination at SOLR Query level? I mean should I be using Deep pagination of SOLR Query to improve the performance?
I added the code as below:

```
HttpSolrServer searcherServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setRequestHandler("/export");
solrQuery.setQuery(query);
solrQuery.set("fl","field1");
solrQuery.setSort(SolrQuery.SortClause.asc("field1"));
QueryResponse resp = searcherServer.query(solrQuery);
```

In Schema.xml I added docValues="true" to field1 and in solrconfig.xml I added as given here https://home.apache.org/~ctargett/RefGuidePOC/jekyll-full/exporting-result-sets.html

Comment: did you try it by yourself?

Comment: Are you designing an export? Paging is something different done by a human, page by page. I do not know of users that page manually through millions of pages.

Comment: Yeah, I am designing export kinda

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated requestHandler for exporting result sets - the `/export` request handler. This is tuned for these situations where you're going to return millions of rows, and want to return the complete set of hits.

There is a few requirements for the export requestHandler:

> All the fields being sorted and exported must have [docValues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues) set to true.
>
> All queries must include sort and fl parameters, or the query will return an error.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/export?q=my-query&sort=severity+desc,timestamp+desc&fl=severity,timestamp,msg
```

The request handler is detailed at the [Exporting result sets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets) wiki page.

Comment: I am gonna try this and update whether it helped me or not. Thank you!

Comment: I am using SOLR Query on the client side (It's a java code). I tried to use export, but I think I am missing something. It's giving me an exception "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ({msg=XMLWriter does not support version: 2,code=400})" 

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have added my code. Kindly let me know what have I missed.

Comment: Try the request directly in your browser (or from `curl` or something similar) first to see what's happening. It's not `dataValues` either - the correct setting is `docValues`, and it will require a reindex. You don't have to add anything in your solrconfig either, as long as you're using a recent version of Solr (where the `/export` handler is mandatory). And if you're forcing `xsort` as the output format, SolrJ probably won't understand that. Let it use it's own `wt` definition (probably javabin).

Comment: yeah it's docValues. I have mentioned it correctly in the file.

Comment: @sridharnetha If you have a question, create a question with all the relevant details and examples.

Comment: @MatsLindh I posted my question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815155/why-solr-not-exporting-result-sets-from-all-cores-of-a-collection). I hope you can answer, I really appreciate your help.