# Why SOLR not exporting result Sets from all cores of a collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

In my SolrCloud 9.0, I have set up a collection (12 string fields) with multiple cores. The following `/export` request handler query is not returning with full documents/datasets.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection_name/export?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=*:*&fq=((Ar:(*srikanth*))%20OR%20(F_Name:(*srikanth*))%20OR%20(Mobile:(*srikanth*))%20OR%20(Name:(*srikanth*))%20OR%20(O_m_no:(*srikanth*))%20OR%20(Addr:(*srikanth*)))&wt=json&sort=id+desc&fl=Name,Mobile,F_Name
```

Collection is already configured with `docvalues=true`. The export request is returning the results different on every refresh/hit but not returning the full dataset.

Occurring the same issue on `/stream` request, my `/stream` request URL as follows,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection_name/stream? 
expr=search(my_collection_name,
q="*:*",
fq="((Ar:(*sridhar*))OR(DOB:(*sridhar*))OR(Email:(*sridhar*))OR(F_Name:(*sridhar*))OR(Gender:(*sridhar*))OR(Mobile:(*sridhar*))OR(Name:(*sridhar*))OR(Nationality:(*sridhar*))OR(O_m_no:(*sridhar*))OR(Addr:(*sridhar*))OR(Pincode:(*sridhar*))OR(State:(*sridhar*)))",
sort="id desc", 
fl="id,Ar,DOB,Email,F_Name,Gender,Mobile,Name,Nationality,
O_m_no,Addr,Pincode,State")
```

Additionally I included the params `zkHost`, `qt` in the `/stream` request URL. **This time the response is taking long and is giving the full dataset**, but most of the time occurring timeout exception `java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException`. **In this case How can we improve the performance?**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection_name/stream? 
expr=search(my_collection_name,
zkHost="localhost:9983",
qt="/export",
q="*:*",
fq="((Ar:(*sridhar*))OR(DOB:(*sridhar*))OR(Email:(*sridhar*))OR(F_Name:(*sridhar*))OR(Gender:(*sridhar*))OR(Mobile:(*sridhar*))OR(Name:(*sridhar*))OR(Nationality:(*sridhar*))OR(O_m_no:(*sridhar*))OR(Addr:(*sridhar*))OR(Pincode:(*sridhar*))OR(State:(*sridhar*)))",
sort="id desc", 
fl="id,Ar,DOB,Email,F_Name,Gender,Mobile,Name,Nationality,
O_m_no,Addr,Pincode,State")
```

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: IIRC - `/export` only works _for the local node_. I'm guessing your query just gets routed to different nodes each time. Have you considered using `/stream` instead with a streaming expression?

Comment: @MatsLindh I added `/stream` request and updated my question. `/stream` request is also returning the results different on every refresh/hit but not returning the full dataset.

Comment: According to your question you get the complete dataset. What is different in the dataset? What does a plain old select query show (and why doesn't that work good enough)? You might have to consider that part of your problem is your query - since that query means that Lucene has to look at _every token_ for _every field_ listed; which will scale very, very badly. If this is what you think all your queries will be like, you probably want to trade disk space for lookup time and use an ngramfilter instead.